# Python. Timedelta. Сложить текущее время с данными, которые приходят с бд, с типом timedelta

Tags: python-3.x

Суть вопроса:
Необходимо сложить текущее время, с данными, которые приходят с БД, по айдишнику, с типом timedelta. Например 2019-02-05 12:47:28.593000 и 00:01:00 и получить 2019-02-05 12:48:28.593000. Данные, которые приходят с БД, статичны, но мне хотелось бы не прибегать к хардкоду а работать с объектом динамически. Буду благодарен за помощь, либо за ссылку на источник с решением похожего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> a = datetime.now()
>>> str(a)
'2019-04-25 00:14:22.514835'

>>> b = timedelta(hours=2, seconds=15)
>>> str(b)
'2:00:15'

>>> str(a+b)
'2019-04-25 02:14:37.514835'
```